# Hide div if screen is smaller than a certain width

Tags: jquery, hide, resolution, show

I want to hide a floating div if the user screen is < 1024px as it will overlay with my blog content area. I found this jQuery on the net but I am not sure how to use it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if ((screen.width>1024)) {
    // if screen size is 1025px wide or larger
    $(".yourClass").css('display', 'none'); // you can also use $(".yourClass").hide();
}
elseif ((screen.width<=1024))  {
    // if screen size width is less than 1024px
    $(".yourClass").css('display', 'block'); // here you can also use show();
}
});
```

If my floating div class name is sharecontent, should I replace the above script like below? If yes, it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if ((screen.width>1024)) {
    // if screen size is 1025px wide or larger
    $(".sharecontent").css('display', 'none'); // you can also use $(".yourClass").hide();
}
elseif ((screen.width<=1024))  {
    // if screen size width is less than 1024px
    $(".sharecontent").css('display', 'block'); // here you can also use show();
}
});
```

I also tried replacing the screen.width with window.width but still no success :(

Comment: Don't use Javascript to fix a non-Javascript problem. Better to fix the CSS

Comment: And in any case, why does it matter what size my screen is? I might not have my browser window full screen

Comment: Gareth raises an important point, you should look at the window width, not the screen really.

Answer (score 109):

Use [media queries](http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/). Your CSS code would be:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .yourClass {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: The support for media queries is not complete in browsers yet as far as I'm aware.  I think IE9 has support, but not IE8 is that right?

Comment: @Orbling: Correct, unfortunately

Answer (score 18):

I have the almost the same situation as yours; that if the screen width is less than the my specified width it should hide the div. This is the jquery code I used that worked for me.

```
$(window).resize(function() {

  if ($(this).width() < 1024) {

    $('.divIWantedToHide').hide();

  } else {

    $('.divIWantedToHide').show();

    }

});
```

Comment: thank you, i replaced `.resize` to `.width` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715124/jquery-do-something-if-screen-width-is-less-than-960-px)

Comment: @stom: if you replace resize() with width() it will change the behaviour - the hidden thing won't reappear until reload. Unless you want it it's not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code seems to be the elseif-statement which should be `else if` (Notice the space).

I rewrote and simplyfied the code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    if (screen.width < 1024) {
        $(".yourClass").hide();
    }
    else {

        $(".yourClass").show();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your logic not round the wrong way in that example, you have it hiding when the screen is bigger than 1024.  Reverse the cases, make the `none` in to a `block` and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having is my css media queries and my IF statement in Jquery clashing. They were both set to 700px but one would think it's hit 700px before the other.

To get around this I created a empty Div right at the top of my HTML(outside my main container)

```
<div id="max-width"></div>
```

In css I set this div to display none

```
 #max-width {
        display: none;
    }
```

In my JS created a function

```
var hasSwitched = function () {
    var maxWidth = parseInt($('#max-width').css('max-width'), 10);
    return !isNaN(maxWidth);
};
```

So in my IF statement instead of saying if (hasSwitched<700) perform the following code, I did the following

```
if (!hasSwitched()) { Your code

}

else{ your code

}
```

By doing this CSS tells Jquery when it's hit 700px. So css and jquery are both synchronized... rather than having a couple of pixels difference. Do give this a try peeps it shall definitely not disappoint.

To get this same logic working for IE8 I used the Respond.js plugin(which also definitely works) It lets you use media queries for IE8. Only thing that wasn't supported was the viewport width and viewport height... hence my reason to try get my css and JS working together. Hope this helps you guys