# Hide A DIV if screen is narrower than 1280px

Tags: javascript, hide, show

I'm trying to implement a floating div that automatically detects the screen resolution of the user. IF the resolution is lower than 1280, a certain div will be automatically hidden.

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277872/hide-a-div-if-screen-is-narrower-than-1024px) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296012/hide-div-if-screen-is-smaller-than-1024) and tried to use those codes but it's not working for me. I'm using wordpress and pasted the js code in the `</header>`

The codes i pasted in my header:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    var screen = $(window)    

    if (screen.width < 1280) {
        $("#floatdiv").hide();
    }
    else {

        $("#floatdiv").show();
    }

});

//run on document load and on window resize
$(document).ready(function () {
    //on load
    hideDiv();
    //on resize
    $(window).resize(function(){
        hideDiv();
    });
}); 
</script>
```

unfortunately, i can't make it work. what seems to be the problem here?

Comment: this can be done by css3 media query is it an option ?

Comment: Can you share the whole HTML?

Comment: Have you properly included the jQuery library? Does the div have that exact `id`?

Comment: I've edited my code. the div id = "#floatdiv"

Comment: Apart from the Media Queries you simply have to call *screen.width()* as it's a jQuery method and not a property.  BTW a variable name of *screen* is probably a pretty bad idea.

Comment: @m90, how do i do that? if you can rewrite it?

Comment: Try `if (screen.width() < 1280) {` instead of the current if.

Comment: Just use another name for your *screen* var and add the *()* when you are checking for the width in the condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace "screen.width" with "window.innerWidth"

Comment: Wow Adam, I've tried your advice and it worked! Hooooooooooooooooray! lol. been working on this for an hour and you just looked at my code and instantly solve it. Thanks!

Comment: last question, is this library has something to do with my code?

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

or I can now delete it?

Comment: If you want to use the .ready(), .hide() and .show() methods you'll still need the jQuery library.

Comment: Have a look at this page: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui. The link you posted is the main jQuery library, but you need to put the jqueryui file after the main jQuery library

Comment: Ignore that comment above this. Yes you need that library for the code you posted.

Answer (score 3):

How about using CSS media queries? You can add one that matches screens narrower than 1280px and set `display: none;` on the div.

```
@media (max-width: 1280px) {
    #floatdiv {
       display: none;
       /* or, to just hide the contents but leave it in the layout of the page: */
       visibility: hidden;
   }
}
```

Comment: user haven't told that css3 as an option

Comment: Hi Ivan, thanks. Is CSS Media queries compatible with IE 7 and 8? I'm worried about compatibility.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries - so no, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: @ScarletAriadneVela No, afaik they require IE9 or later.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not concerned about the old browsers (Internet Explorer) the easiest way to do this is not JavaScript but [CSS3 Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).

More information about the browsers comptability [here](http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries).
Thanks to [Ivan Vergiliev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596167/ivan-vergiliev).

```css
 @media (max-width: 1280px) {
   #floatdiv {
     display: none;
   }
 }
```

This means than the CSS will be applied only if the width of the screen is smaller than 1280px.

**Edited**

Comment: user haven't told that css3 as an option

Comment: more concerned of the compatibility with older IE.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the screen width by `screen.availWidth`

```
 $("#floatdiv").show();

 while(screen.availWidth < 1280){
      $("#floatdiv").hide();

 }
```

Comment: Yes, but `screen.width` should also correctly return a width for the comparison.