# How do I make a div not display, if the browser window is at a certain width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic

I want some images to not be displayed if the persons browser window is too small. Would I do this in CSS or Javasript, and if so, how?

Comment: div.style.display = 'none';

Comment: @PrasathK: "if the persons browser window is too small".

Comment: @PrasathK: an `if` isn't a loop.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px){ /* max screen size */
    #div { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: Is that dynamic, so will change each time the user resizes the window?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use JavaScript, you can simply do it with CSS `@media queries`

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) { /* Change Width Here */
  div.class_name {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in **css** using **@media tags**

```
   /*Show images for resolution greated than 1024*/
   @media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {        
    img{ /*show all images*/
        display:block;
    }         
    }
    /*hide images for resolution lesser than 1024*/
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {        
    img{ /*hide all images*/
        display:none;
    }        
    }
```

In @media tags you can target specific device or all like **screen** alone, affect in **print** , **mobile** device etc or **all**

For doing this in **javascript/jquery** refer the below post,

[How to detect in jquery if screen resolution changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575772/how-to-detect-in-jquery-if-screen-resolution-changes)

Comment: I'm *pretty* sure it's called @media *query*