# hide DIV and replace with a DIV if window is narrower than

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I found this topic [Hide A DIV if screen is narrower than 1024px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277872/hide-a-div-if-screen-is-narrower-than-1024px) and I want to get something similar with quoted code below, a code for this kind of response: to hide one div ( id="krug_wide" ) if a window is narrower then 1280px and to replace that hidden div with another one ( id="krug_small" ).

I also found out the page http://www.fryed.co.uk/labs/resize_div_on_window_resize connected with mentioned topic. I still can not figure out the right and appropriate syntax but I'm sure it is "a piece of cake" for you.

Thank you in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var screen = $(window)    

    if (screen.width < 1024) {
        $("#krug_wide").hide();
    }
    else {

        $("#floatdiv").show();
    }

});
```

Comment: No need for javascript here, use a CSS [Media Query](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Media Queries**](http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-web-design-with-media-queries) ou have example on this link

> A media query consists of a media type and zero or more expressions
>   that check for the conditions of particular media features.

**with on CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    //Some property here
    #krug_wide{
       ...
    }
}
```

**Or create different CSS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width:1280px)" href="example.css" />
```

You have many example on [**W3C Media Queries**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following mediaquery in css

```
@media only screen (max-device-width: 1023px) {
  .content { // Your div's class name to hide
     display: none;
  }
}
```