# jQuery - Get Screen Size Width

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to grab the screen size and add an if / else query, but for some reason I can't get it to work

What I'm looking for is if the screen width is larger / equal 480px, the following should be outputted:

```
{$pPage = $cWidth}
```

Else this:

```
{$pPage = 1}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {    
        {$pPage = $cWidth}    
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Anybody out there with advice how to add the the query in reference to the screen.width, so that it also works?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715124/jquery-do-something-if-screen-width-is-less-than-960-px

Answer (score 35):

**try this:**

**using jquery:**

```
if ($(window).width() < 1280) {
   alert('Less than 1280');
}
else {
   alert('More than 1280');
}
```

**OR**

**using javascript:**

```
var screensize = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
if (screensize  < 1280) {
   alert('Less than 1280');
}
else {
   alert('More than 1280');
}
```

Comment: Many thx, jquery version works. Amending it however to my needs doesn't work. Keeps returning the last defined value. Any idea why? `if ($(window).width() < 1280) { {$pPage = 1}; } else { {$pPage = 3}; }`

Comment: ternary! `var $pPage = ($(window).width() < 1280) ? 1 : 3;` - might also need to wrap in resize hook: `$(window).resize(function () {var $pPage = ($(window).width() < 1280) ? 1 : 3; doSomethingWith($pPage);})`