# Why is my resize event not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, height

My DIV #sequence is to be full height of the browser window for window sizes greater than 920px in height. When its greater than 920px in height I want to fire a plugin, for window sizes lower than 920px I want the #sequence div to be the height set in my CSS file as a fallback. This works when the page is loaded, however I cannot get the resize event to fire, its unresponsive and I see no errors in console.

This is my code mostly taken from this post [Do something if screen width is less than 960 px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715124/jquery-do-something-if-screen-width-is-less-than-960-px):

```
var eventFired = 0;

if ($(window).height() < 920) {

} else {
    fitSequence();  
    eventFired = 1;
}

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if (!eventFired == 1) {
        if ($(window).height() < 920) {

        } else {
            $(window).resize(function(){ fitSequence(); });
        }
    }
});
```

Just as an FYI here's the fitSequence plugin I'm referencing:

```
function fitSequence(){
var height=$(window).height();

$('#sequence').css('height',height-100+"px");
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If condition is not correct:

```
if (!eventFired == 1) {
```

It should be:

```
if (eventFired != 1) {
```

And in the function part this is ambiguous part of code:

```
$('#sequence').css('height',height-100+"px");
```

It should be:

```
$('#sequence').css('height',(height-100)+"px");
                           ^^ add brackets
```

Comment: That fixes most of it thanks for the pointers! I forgot about  resetting the height of my div for in-frequent occasions when you resize your window back to a smaller height. I fix this by using media queries at the bottom of my styles.css: @media screen and (max-height : 920px) { #sequence { height: 600px !important; } }