# How to change javascript advertising source base on screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, ads

I want to add advertising to my website. But the ad company not provide the responsive solution.

All I got was two script sources for pc and mobile.

```
web

728*90
<script src="http://xxx_728_90&ad_type=banner"></script> 

mobiles

320*50
<script src="http://xxx_320_50&ad_type=banner"></script>
```

It will be ok if I have two versions for pc and mobile but I only have one.
My question is how to change the ad script source base on screen size.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715124/do-something-if-screen-width-is-less-than-960-px

Comment: use the window resize event to change the src of the document element

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily have to implement the script as HTML. You can script your scripts!

To do this you will need a mechanism to decide whether you are running on a desktop or mobile. For simplicity, I will use the [screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen) object, which contains useful data about the physical device. This approach is a bit naive, consider using the [viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8876069/2990144) and listen to [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) events to respond to changes to the window size (if the library can tolerate being re-loaded).

```
const isDesktop = screen.width > 700;
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://xxx_' + (isDesktop ? '728_90' : '320_50') + '&ad_type=banner';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: I got this error: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': Only one element on document allowed.

Comment: @VuongTran Quick typing = bugs. :) I edited the answer, try again.

Comment: another one: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: @VuongTran That is because the URL you gave in the question is invalid. I am not sure where `http://xxx_728_90` came from, but I can't fix that. You will need to figure out the correct URL for the advertising library and use it. I assume the `xxx` is supposed to be replaced with some kind of site ID.

Comment: xxx was example. I fix it. But the ad not display :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution.

```
<script src="http://media.krxd.net/derek/postscribe.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<div id="ad"></div>
 <script>

 // jQuery used as an example of delaying until load.
  $(function() { 
     if ( $(window).width() > 739) {      
  //Add your javascript for large screens here 
  var str='728_90';
} 
else {
  //Add your javascript for small screens here 
  var str='320_100';
}
    // Build url params and make the ad call
    postscribe('#ad', '<script src=xxx'+str+'&ad_type=banner><\/script>');
  });

</script>
</div>
```