# HTML Change Class Name Based on Screen Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the name of a class tag dynamically when a user loads the page based off of the screen size.  Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="changeClass()">

<section class="example">
    <p>Hello</p>
</section>

<section class="example">
    <p>New section</p>
</section>

<script>
function changeClass() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('example');
    var width = (window.innerHeight > 0) ? window.innerHeight : screen.Height;
    console.log(width);
    if(width <= 640) {
        while(x.length > 0) {
            x[1].className ='newClass'; 
        }
    } else {
        while(x.length > 0) {
            x[0].className = "example";
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, the page is thrown into an infinite loop and cannot load the data.  Is there an easy way to set the class named based on the size of the screen?  Can I use an "if conditional" check when the page loads?  I have also included a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wsdzcfnh/).  I don't know how much that will help however.

Comment: why are you doing this with javascript and not media queries in css? it's a bit overkill to use javascript to handle style changes.

Comment: Is your end goal to apply different styles to an element based on the screen size? Or is there another reason to change the class name?

Comment: I am just looking for the easiest way to do this.  People online were suggesting Javascript.  I just want to change the element name based off of the screen size.

Comment: media queries is more than enough if your primary goal is to change style based of screen size

Comment: I need to change the class name specifically inside of the element tag.

Comment: I am already using media queries.  I have to specifically change the class name inside of the tag.

Comment: Why do you need to change the class? that is the crux of the problem here. answer below is correct. Are you're using classes to create code behavior ?

Comment: You can try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715124/do-something-if-screen-width-is-less-than-960-px#answer-34995563) by leymannx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, media queries are the best way to achieve what you're trying to do here.

That said, to answer the actual question as it currently stands with your code, you are getting into an infinite loop because you are using a `while` loop. The length of the array will never reach zero, so your `while` loop will never exit.

Consider using the following code

```
if(width <= 640) {
    for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].className ='newClass'; 
    }
}
```

Obviously you would need to change both `while` loops.

All that said though, I would **strongly** recommend you use media queries for this unless you have a compelling reason not to.

If the idea is just to change styles based on screen size, you could accomplish this with the following addition to your stylesheet

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    .example {
        ... styles to show on smaller screens ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I know how to use media queries.  They way I wrote the code needs to be fixed.  I was just looking for an easier way out for this specific issue I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of problems that I can see in your code. The first thing is the way you are getting the screen width is incorrect.

it should be corrected as below.

```
var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.Width;
```

And the second thing is you don't need any loop at all. Just following code will be more than enough to achieve what you are looking for.

```
function changeClass() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName('example');
    var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.Width;
    console.log(width);
    if(x.length > 0) {
        if(width <= 640) {
            x[1].className ='newClass'; 
        } else {
            x[0].className = "example";
        }
    }
}
```