# Changing Placeholder Text with JavaScript Based on a Media Query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, media-queries

I am trying to write a JS script that will change the text values of inputs' placeholder attributes when the screen size hits a width of <= 400px, so that the text is shortened rather than cut-off on a smaller screen. I've looked around the site here and for other resources that can show me how to use media queries in JS, but so far, none have worked-- Either no change is seen at any width, or the shorter text is applied regardless of whether or not it is at/under 400. The code I have currently is shown below; it is one of the versions that shortens the text regardless of the width of the screen:

```
<script>
    if(document.documentElement.clientWidth < 400){
            $("[placeholder='State/Province']").attr('placeholder', 'State/Prov.');
            $("[placeholder='Vehicle Series']").attr('placeholder', 'Series');
            $("[placeholder='Engine Size']").attr('placeholder', 'Eng. Size');
            $("[placeholder='Transmission Type']").attr('placeholder', 'Trans.');
    }
</script>
```

Other variations I have tried to use as the "if" conditional are...

```
if(screen.width < 400px){...}

if(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)")){...}
```

Other suggestions mentioned using event handlers and other methods, but if a media query-like solution is available, that's what I'd prefer to use. Either vanilla Javascript or jQuery will work. Any ideas and constructive advice will be appreciated-- Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7715187/2729634

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($(window).width() < 400) {
 // Code here...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, but this made the longer version of the text reappear with no change at any width. This is one stubborn code block! lol

Comment: Hmm.. Did you reload the page after changing the screen width?

Comment: Yeah, a few times. Cleared the cache, too :-/

Comment: When I checked out the codepen in Chrome it didn't work-- Is there something in the Chrome dev tools that would prevent it from working? That's what I'm currently using to demo this-- it's worked for everything else, so I didn't see why it wouldn't work in this case, but maybe there is something funky about this kind of thing when resizing in Chrome? I checked it out on Blisk and the Codepen worked, so I checked to see if my code worked there, but is doesn't, so I'm still at a loss as to what's going on here...

Comment: It's working for me in Chrome, so I don't think it's the dev tools. After making the screen smaller, I refresh the browser and the placeholder text changes.

Comment: Hmmm... I'll fiddle with it some more and see what happens. I believe it's working and SHOULD work, I just don't why it's not working for ME lol If I find out why, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would use two seperate attributes, one for larger screens, one for mobile.  That way, you can have a more responsive design.  For instance, what if a user opens your code in a very small window then scales it, they still have the mini version.  But, in the new code, it the new placeholders will populate.  Why not just add a hook that'll check for resize **and** modify the placeholder appropriately:

```js
 $(window).resize(function () {
  if ($(document.body).width() < 400){ //your original issue was here
   $("input[placeholder-mobile]").each(function () {
    $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).attr('placeholder-mobile'));
   });
  } else {
   $("input[placeholder-mobile]").each(function () {
    $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).attr('placeholder-full'));
   });
  }
 });

 $(window).resize();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder-full="State/Province" placeholder-mobile="State/Prov." type="text" /><br />
 <input placeholder-full="Vehicle Series" placeholder-mobile="Series" type="text" /><br />
 <input placeholder-full="Engine Size" placeholder-mobile="Eng. Size" type="text" /><br />
 <input placeholder-full="ransmission Type" placeholder-mobile="Trrans." type="text" />
```

Comment: Still no luck :( But thank you very much for replying-- It's an interesting suggestion. Wish I knew why none of this is working!!

Comment: The code does work... Maybe you have the resolution wrong on the phone or something.