# Detecting and changing via screen width is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, screen-resolution

So, I checked out [Do something if screen width is less than 960 px](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715124/do-something-if-screen-width-is-less-than-960-px) to see how to execute something if the screen size was less than 960 `px`. However, it did not work for me. Their answer was this:

```
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
   alert('Less than 960');
}
else {
   alert('More than 960');
}
```

I tried it and it did work. I also already had an `alert` that told me the screen size;

```
var size = $(window).width();
alert(size);
```

and this worked, but this did not:

```
if (size < 1200) {
    $("#mobileVersionDetected").css("display", "block");
}
else {
    $("#mobileVersionDetected").css("display", "none");
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: No need for javascript if all you are doing is hiding/showing elements. Use css media queries

Comment: To echo @charlietfl, this is exactly what **[CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)** are for. They eliminate the need for script and are more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I add `$(window).width()` into the actual `if` `function` rather than using a `variable` it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (size < 1200) {
    $('#mobileVersionDetected').attr("style", "display: block");
}
else {
    $('#mobileVersionDetected').attr("style", "display: none");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To echo @charlietfl, this is exactly what **[CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)** are for. They eliminate the need for script and are more efficient.

```css
    /* Baseline styles applied initially: */
    body { background-color: #b200ff; /* purple */ }

    p    { 
      border:1px solid black; 
      background: white; 
      padding:5px; 
      text-align:center; 
      font:bold 1.2em Arial;

    }

    /* 
       When writing multiple media queries that don't explicitly
       specify a range, the order of the queries matter!!!

       For example:

          With a viewport of 400px wide, both of the the following 
          two queries would apply:

           @media screen and (max-width:400px) {...}
           @media screen and (max-width:600px) {...}

      So, the last one would be used. 
    */

    /*
       Note that this query uses "min-width", 
       not "max-width" so that it handles
       all viewports bigger than 1200       
    */
    @media screen and (min-width: 1201px) {
      body { background-color: orange; }
      p:after { content: "over 1200px"; }
    }

    /* 
       Here, we're using "max-width" to handle
       viewports up to the specified sizes:
    */
    @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
      body { background-color: yellow; }
      p:after { content: "961px to 1200px"; }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
      body { background-color: blue; }
      p:after { content: "769px to 960px"; }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      body { background-color: grey; }
      p:after { content: "551px to 768px"; }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 550px) {
      body { background-color: green; }
      p:after { content: "321px to 550px"; }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width:320px) {
      body { background-color: red; }
      p:after { content: "up to 320px wide"; }
    }
```

```html
<p></p>
```