# Show/hide different amount of elements by resolution

Tags: html, css, css-float, media-queries

I got some divs with a fixed width and height and they should push to left to all size of screen

What I want to achive is that based on resoulotion I want to show/hide some of them.

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/24Lwmnpj/)**

For example:

- 1024px - show 3 elements
- 1400px - show 5 elements

What is the best way to do this?

Here's my CSS:

```
.square{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:salmon;
  margin:5px;
  float:right;
}

.container{
  position:relative;
}

.wrapper-div{
  position: absolute;
  width: 1000px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%; 
}
```

Comment: you will need to change the `.wrapper-div` `width` based on the resolution using `@media query`

Comment: is the approach that i use correct ? i center them with transform and after that i'm gonna push them left

Comment: you can use `margin:0 auto` as it `div` a `block` element it will work

Comment: Seems that this question has been made yet. Please try to not ask things that could have been asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296012/hide-div-if-screen-is-smaller-than-a-certain-width

Comment: how to push them left with overflow hidden and when size changed other div show up

Answer (score 1):

Yes this could be done easily with @media-queries.

A simple example of media queries are:

In the head of your html page you do:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And the divs with the content:

```
<div class="square">

</div>
```

The css will look like this:

```
 @media (max-width:1024px) and (min-width:0px) {
    .square{
         your css width and etc..
    }
}​

  @media (max-width:1400px) and (min-width:1025px) {
    .square{
         your css width and etc..
    }
}​
```

More about it [HERE](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Comment: i know the media query very well , the question is about correct soloution

Comment: and how to push them left with overflow hidden and when size changed other div show up

Comment: give your width in percentage for example 0 to 1200 media query width for square will be 33.33% or based on your margins and above 1200 width will be 20%.

Comment: @sani Then you should combine the media queries with the [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) pseudo selector. `.square:nth-child(n+3)`

Comment: Look : i want to push them left with a fix width and add overflow hidden for not having scroll

Comment: and overflow makes other div hidden based on screen size

Answer (score 0):

You should combine the [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) with [:nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) to handle that

CSS example code:

```
.square {
  /* Your square css */
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  /* left displayed only the first 3th blocks */
  .square:nth-child(n+4) {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}​

@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  /* left displayed only the first 5th blocks */
  .square:nth-child(n+6) {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}​
```